# URL_For in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I need to access sub directories which contains images show that i can show it in HTML. How can i do this.

[image: MyFlask Directory]

Am building am image **scraper**. In above image I have shown my Flask directory. The name images is constant name where as the sub flder name is dynamic, it is the name of the search term i give.

[image: This is my results.HTML]

In above the {{results}} gives my dynamic name of the folder which is the search term.

Comment: Do not post screenshots, paste code as a text

Comment: Hi, Am sorry that I could not do full post as many files are interlinked

Answer (score 2):

`url_for` provides the path to a previously defined route. I'm guessing that you did not create a route for delivering these images. You can either:

**move the `images`-folder to your `static` folder**

This way you can access them via

`<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/programming/jpg_0.jpg') }}">`

**or create an image-route, like**

```
import os
from flask import send_file

@app.route('/getImage/<string:imgName>')
def getImage(imgName)
    filePath = 'ABSOLUTE_PATH'
    return send_file(os.path.join(filePath, imgName))
```

You can then access the images via

`<img src="{{ url_for('getImage', imgName='jpg_0.jpg') }}">`

You should also think about letting your static files being served directly by a web server like `nginx` or `Apache`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the amazing reply. This is starting to make sense for me as did not have idea of how URL_For works. Could you please help me with this.  Here the ABSOLUTE PATH should also contain my dynamic search term right? For Ex: - filePath = "./images/Programming/jpg_0.jpg'. How will I pass Programming, from URL_For?

Comment: For the pure purpose of delivering images, I would just move them into you `static`-folder. Just create a directory called `static` in the same folder where you created your `templates`-directory.

Comment: `filePath` would be the path where you images are stored. The simplest would be (Windows) `C:\\Users\\User\\ ... \\images\\Programming` or (Linux) `/home/user/ ... /images/Programming`. You could also call this route with a second parameter to determine the correct filePath. You should maybe read the following: https://pythonise.com/series/learning-flask/sending-files-with-flask, 
https://stackabuse.com/serving-static-files-with-flask